# Use Numpy Multidimensional Array Slicing Without Using the [slice,slice] Syntax?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Is there are a way to use Numpy's multidimensional array slicing without using the [slice, slice] syntax?

I need to be able to use it from normal function calls, but I haven't found a way to use the slice object to do it.

I cannot use the syntax `[(slice,slice)]` for my program because `[]` is special syntax outside of regular function calls.
The language I am using is Hy, a Lisp for Python, and it does not support this syntax.  More importantly, it shouldn't support this syntax.  Numpy, however, doesn't seem to support multidimensional slicing without using the `[]` syntax.

What's tripping me up is that the mix of C and Python in the Numpy source makes it difficult to discern how the `[slice,slice]` is implemented.
It may not even be possible to circumvent this syntax.

EDIT:

The answer provided below by @Joe Kington allows one to slice Numpy matrices like so:

`x = np.array([list(range(5)) for x in list(range(5))])
x.getitem(slice(1,4))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
x.getitem(tuple([slice(1,4),slice(1,4)]))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])`

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and how exactly it failed? What constitutes an abnormal function call?

Comment: `[bla, blah]` is just `[(blah, blah)]` I bet there are many questions about this...

Comment: I have edited the question to further clarify.  Please let me know if it remains unclear.

Comment: this question may be a better fit for the numpy github, but i'm surprised this hasn't been encountered before and thought it might be best if instead done in a more public forum like stackoverflow in case someone in the future needs clarification

Comment: It sounds like you want `arr.__getitem__(tuple_of_slice_objects)`, and `__setitem__` for assignment. (Incidentally, your edits helped make the question much more clear. I think it's a good question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description, it seems like you're asking what function calls are used to implement slicing and slice assignment.

Python uses the "special" methods `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to implement and/or allow customization of how slicing works.  Any class that implements these can be sliced.  There's actually nothing numpy-specific about this.

In other words

```
x = arr[4:10, 9:15, ::-1]
x[0] = 100
```

is translated into

```
x = arr.__getitem__((slice(4, 6), slice(9, 10), slice(None, None, -1)))
x.__setitem__(0, 100)
```

For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print 'Getting', index
    def __setitem__(self, index, val):
        print 'Setting', index, 'to', val

f = Foo()
print 'Getting...'
f[:]
f[4:10, ::-1, ...]

print 'Equivalently:'
f.__getitem__(slice(None))
f.__getitem__((slice(4, 10), slice(None, None, -1), Ellipsis))

print 'Setting...'
f[0] = 1
f[5:10, 100] = 2
f[...] = 100

print 'Equivalently:'
f.__setitem__(0, 1)
f.__setitem__((slice(5,10), 100), 2)
f.__setitem__(Ellipsis, 100)
```

Also, it can be handy to know about `numpy.index_exp` (or equivalently, `np.s_`). It's nothing fancy -- it just translates slicing into the equivalent tuple, etc. It's quite similar to our `Foo` class above. For example:

```
In [1]: np.index_exp[10:4, ::-1, ...]
Out[1]: (slice(10, 4, None), slice(None, None, -1), Ellipsis)
```

Comment: fantastic!  that was unexpectedly straightforward, thanks so much!
i'm going to edit my question to give a summary of this solution's use in numpy

Comment: Nice explanation about how slicing works under the hood and how slice objects are represented.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to pass the slice through as a parameter?

```
def do_slice(sl, mystring):
    return mystring[sl]

sl = slice(0,2)
mystr = "Hello"

print do_slice(sl, mystr)
```